# running git 'post-receive' hook with setuid fails

Tags: c++, git, ubuntu, permissions, setuid

I have a git repository that needs to run a post-receive hook as sudo.  The binary that I compiled to test this looks like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int ret;
   ret = setuid(geteuid());
   if(!ret) {
      fprintf(stderr, "error setting uid %d \n", ret);
   }       
   system("[...command only sudo can access...]");

   return 0;
}
```

The `geteuid()` retrieves the owner id of `post-receive`, then tries to setuid.  When running this with any user(including the super user) it runs the script correctly as root.  However, when triggered by the git hook the systems fail to set the uid.  I have tried running `chmod u+s post-receive`  I also tried some other configurations, but I am running out of ideas.  Any reason why it would work in all cases except when git triggers it?

btw, platform Ubuntu Server 9.04(2.6.28-15), git1.6.0.4, gcc version 4.3.3 (Ubuntu 4.3.3-5ubuntu4)

Comment: One issue is that you print an error message but then continue to execute the system() call.  You also ignore the result of the system() call and then exit with a success (0) status.

Comment: @Blake: The "-as the- with any user" bit is unclear - does the program run correctly when run as the user you're pushing as? I think the closest way to duplicate the environment it's run in by git would be: `ssh hostname 'cd /path/to/repo; .git/hooks/post-receive'`

Comment: Why not let the users run the command directly with sudo (configure it with visudo, specify 'NOPASSWD:')?  Writing your own suid-root wrapper is risky.

Comment: I think you have a setup problem if you want a hook to run with elevated privileges. You'd best reconsider the file ownerships and permissions.

Answer (score 1):

1. The file system where the git repo is stored may be mounted with the nosuid option
2. If you are pushing over ssh the suid capability may be disabled for commands invoked with ssh (no CAP_SETUID)

In any case, what you are trying to do is very inadvisable.

Answer (score 1):

1. Run your program as a daemon.
2. Wait for input on a socket/named pipe/msgq.
3. In the hook, send a message to your daemon with whatever info it needs to perform the operation.
4. If needed, send a message back to the hook with status.

This will likely be easier to manage and secure properly.

Answer (score 0):

try running your program from the command prompt

Comment: Works fine when not activated thru git.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a bootstrap script. ie

```
#/usr/bin/sh
./your_program
```

Then make make the script the hook.